# Why am I getting two different answers to this simple calculus of variations problem?

Tags: solution-verification, calculus-of-variations

A worker is disposing of radioactive material of mass $\mu$ and needs to minimize her exposure.  Being near the radioactive material exposures her to radiation at a rate of $\frac {dE_n}{dt}=c\mu$, where $E_n$ is the radiation she gets from being near the material and $c$ is a constant.  However having to pick up the material gives her some addition exposure at a rate of $\frac{dE_p}{dt}=k(\mu')^2$, where $E_p$ is the exposure due to picking up the material, $\mu'$ is the time derivative of $\mu$, and $k$ is another constant.

$1)$ Find a functional for total exposure over some time $\Delta t$.

$2)$ Minimize that functional to find a DE for the amount of material $\mu(t)$.

---

Here's what I've done:

$1)$ $E_{total} = \int_0^{\Delta t} \frac {dE}{dt} dt = \int_0^{\Delta t} \frac {dE_n}{dt} + \frac {dE_p}{dt}dt = \int_0^{\Delta t}[c\mu(t)+k(\mu'(t))^2]dt$.  That one seems relatively easy so I think I did it right.

$2)$ Here I'm having some problems because doing it two different ways, I get two different answers.

First way: use the characteristic equation $\frac {\partial F}{\partial y} - \frac {d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} =0$.

So in this case we have $c-\frac{d}{dt}(2k\mu'(t))=0$.  Therefore $\mu'' = \frac {c}{2k}$.  Therefore $\mu(t) = \frac {c}{2k}t^2+\alpha t+\beta$, for some constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which we find given some initial conditions.

The other way is to use the fact that $F$ doesn't depend on $t$ explicitly (only $\mu$ and $\mu'$ appear explicitly in the equation) so the characteristic equation should "simplify" to $F-\mu'\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mu'}=\gamma$ for some constant $\gamma$.

Then $c\mu+k(\mu')^2-2k(\mu')^2=c\mu-k(\mu')^2=\gamma$.  Since this is nonlinear, I just plugged it into WolframAlpha and am getting some complicated thing with product log functions -- which doesn't seem to be the same as the simple quadratic I got above.

---

So my questions:  Did I do part $1$ correctly?  If so, why am I getting different answers using the two different approachs to part $2$?

Comment: I do believe you did part (1) correctly .. still trying to find out where the mistake might be for part (2).  But my hunch is that the quadratic solution is the correct one.

Comment: I simplified the nonlinear DE and tried WolframAlpha again and this time it gave me a quadratic.  So if you guys think that my general approaches were good here, then I guess I did it right -- Yay!

Comment: Oh haha I just finished writing up a verification that your nonlinear ODE is correct.

Comment: Lol.  OK, well thanks for verifying it for me!  Also, I typed up my solution wrong, on my paper I do have $\dfrac c{4k}$ -- oops.  Anyways, great job and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did part (1) correctly, and your Euler-Lagrange equation
$$
\mu'' = \frac{c}{2k}
$$
is correct.  This gives a solution 
$
\mu(t) = \frac{c}{4k} t^2 + \alpha t + \beta t
$ 
(which is off by a factor of 2 what you wrote).  This also satisfies the nonlinear equation.  To see this, we calculate

\begin{align*}
c\mu - k(\mu')^2 
&= \frac{c^2}{4k}t^2 + c\alpha t + c\beta - k(\frac{c}{2k}t + \alpha)^2 
\\&= \frac{c^2}{4k}t^2 + c\alpha t + c\beta - \frac{c^2}{4k} t^2 - c\alpha t - k\alpha^2 
\\&= c\beta - k\alpha^2.
\end{align*}

The right-hand side is independent of time, so it satisfies the equation you wrote.

In summary, you did everything right except miss a factor of 2 in your quadratic solution.  I don't know what Mathematica is doing with the log-products, maybe it's confused because of the undetermined constant in the ODE.